# How can multiple locks speed up multi-threaded code?

Tags: java, multithreading

How can the `synchronized` statement speed up the code comparing with synchronized method?

```
 public void stageOne() {

    synchronized (lock1) {
        list1.add(random.nextInt(100));
    }
}

public void stageTwo() {

     synchronized (lock2) {
        list2.add(random.nextInt(100));
    }
}
public void process() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        stageOne();
        stageTwo();
    }
}


    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            process();
        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            process();
        }
    });
```

If I use  `public synchronized void stageOne()` and `public synchronized void stageTwo()`, the program will take more time to finish.

Comment: a `synchronized method` almost equals `synchronized(this){ .... }`. So, you are locking the whole object, hence the methods can not run at the same time, while a dedicated lock on the two lists allows each thread to work on one list.

Comment: You probably already see this in the answers below, but just to make it crystal clear:  The difference has nothing to do with synchronized method vs. synchronized statement. The difference is entirely due to one lock vs. two locks.

Comment: @jameslarge *almost* cause there is a tiny difference when synchronizing elements with any subsequent execution on the same instance. `A synchronized` method will cause an update of instances in other threads, once the method returns - a `synchronized(this)` will trigger the update as soon as the lock is released- There could be statements AFTER releasing the lock, which is not possible for `synchronized methods`.

Comment: Note that `stageTwo` should of course not depend on `stageOne` - that is, as any thread can execute any number of either one of these methods between the time that `stageOne` and `stageTwo` are executed in a thread. The names of these methods however seem to indicate that there is a dependency between the method calls.

Comment: @dognose, my mistake, I thought you were comparing a `synchronized` method to a method whose entire body was a single `synchronized(this){...}` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `stageOne()` and `stageTwo()` were declared `synchronized`, they would use the same lock. That lock would be the object that contains these methods. This would mean that the methods cannot be executed simultaneously.

Since you have two methods and two threads, you will have four methods competing for the same lock. If both methods have their own locks, as in the code you supplied, one instance of *each* method can be executed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say each stage needs 1 second to execute, and you start 2 threads.

With a global lock, if one thread executes any of the method, the other thread can't execute any of the method. So the total time will be 2 seconds + 2 seconds = 4 seconds.

```
T1
S1 ---- S2 --- end

T2
wait----------- S1 ---- S2 ---- end
```

With 2 locks, once the first thread has finished executing stage1, the second one can execute stage1 while the first one executes stage2. So, assuming the tasks are completely parallelizable and you have 2 cores, the second thread will wait for 1 second, then do its two stages, and the total time will thus be 3 seconds.

```
T1
S1 ---- S2 --- end

T2
wait--- S1 ----S2 ---- end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Syncronized method locks the whole method.So only one thread can execute that method causing other thread to wait.**

**Syncronized statement locks the block not method so it is faster in comparison to Syncronized method.**

**Example 1(Syncronized method)**:Suppose there is `a public toilet`.There are `2 person` and they both have to `pee`(as fast as they can) but only one can enter the toilet and when it enters it `locks` the door .In this case `Person 2` has to `waits` outside the door for `Person 1` to free the toilet.So same in case of `Syncronized method` thread 2 waits outside the method for thread 1 to free the lock.[Syncronized method Demo](https://ideone.com/0WmrSZ)(8028 ms)

**Example 2(Syncronized block)**:Suppose there is `a public toilet`.There are `2 person` and they both have to `pee`(as fast as they can) but in this case they both can `enter` in the toilet but when they enters they find that there is only `one urinal` in the toilet.But in this case `Person 2` is waiting inside the toilet door for `Person 1` to free the urinal .That doesn't make much difference waiting outside the door or inside but there is a `difference(maybe for few seconds)` .So same in case of `Syncronized block` thread 2 wait inside the function but outside the block for thread 1 to free the lock.So the syncronized block takes less time than syncronized method.[Syncronized block with one lock](https://ideone.com/Xe2J9x)(4252 ms)

The `real advantage` is in using 2 or `more locks` for different threads like when in second example when 2 person enters toilet they find `2 urinals` they both can use different urinals at the same time .Same `thread 1 holds lock 1 for functionn 1 and at the same time thread 2 holds lock 2` for function 2 and later exchnage when they are free .That would probably save more time.[Syncronized block with 2 locks](https://ideone.com/nueIT4)(2138 ms)

You can also check the time difference in each case above for executing the same code for different cases.